# How to change the color the words between two specific words in a sentence

Tags: java, android, textview

I found only how to change the color of a word in a sentence or how to change the color of the sentence.
Can any body tell me how to color all words between two specific notation.
For ex: My name is < pravind kumar > . 
i have to change the color of word pravind kumar. For that i want to traverse every alphabet and change color of every alphabet between < >  .

Comment: I know this type of question should not be asked but please help me

Comment: You can try HTML tag for different color in one sentence.

Comment: or use a SpannableString

Comment: try googling for ForegroundColorSpan

Comment: @user2515300 does you sentence contain more than one name between < and this > ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to bother iterating and parsing your string thats trivial.

```
 SpannableString span1 = new SpannableString("pravind ");
    SpannableString span2 = new SpannableString("kumar");

    span1 .setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, 13, 
                                                   Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       span2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 5, 13, 
                                                   Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);


        mTextView.setText(TextUtils.concat(span1," " ,span2));
```

Comment: I did not have to color any particular word but to color words under any specific notation ex:< ---- > there can be any-word between them

Comment: @user2515300 does the words between < > occur more than once in a sentence like <Name1> and <Name2>?

Comment: yeah so use a regular expression like (/<[^>]*>/g) this will get you all words between <>,you will also get there left and then do the coloring thing and replace back..